# How to play different Videos in Android on different image clicks?

Tags: java

I am newbie in Android Development and i am developing a android app using recycler view and card view.I created two column using grid layout with 10 rows 20 images Now i want to set a click Listener on every image which starts a new activity that should play a giff animation or video link with that specific image.

```
 public AlphabetRecyclerViewItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // Get LayoutInflater object.
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    // Inflate the RecyclerView item layout xml
    View alphabetItemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_card_view_item,parent,false);


    final TextView alphabetTitleView = (TextView)alphabetItemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_image_title);

    // Get alphabet image view object.
    final ImageView alphabetImageView = (ImageView)alphabetItemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_image);
    alphabetImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Get Alphabet title Text
            String alphabetTitle = alphabetTitleView.getText().toString();
            // Create a snackbar and show it.
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(alphabetImageView,"You Clicked" + alphabetTitle + "image",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackbar.show();
        }
    });

    // Create and return our custom Alphabet Recycler View Item Holder object.
    AlphabetRecyclerViewItemHolder ret =new AlphabetRecyclerViewItemHolder(alphabetItemView);
    return ret;
}
```

I want to play different videos on every image user click.

Answer (score 0):

Add your all images and video in arraylist and set arraylist in recycler view 
after setting the adapter use the recyclerview item click and pass the video link from that position to next screen which you want  to play in your video player.